# Why have there been no reviews of The Greatest Showman?

Tags: film-industry, reception, marketing

*The Greatest Showman* will be in theaters in two days, but I cannot find any reviews of it online. Reviews usually come out days or weeks before a movie's release. They are often used by marketers to promote the film ("Best performances of the year!"). I don't think the movie was withheld from reviewers because it's bad, [since it's been nominated for 3 Golden Globe awards](https://www.goldenglobes.com/film/greatest-showman) including "Best Motion Picture - Musical or Comedy".

**So why has *The Greatest Showman* been withheld from reviewers?**

Comment: There are at least two reviews already: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Greatest_Showman#Critical_response Most likely there is an embargo.

Comment: Thanks @BCdotWEB. I hadn't found those. It's still really surprising to me that there are so few reviews that RottenTomatoes has no score yet, one day before the movie opens. It seems as though the movie was kept from most reviewers and that's got me really curious!

Comment: Slashfilm refers to a review embargo, but doesn't site another source or a reason for it. http://www.slashfilm.com/the-greatest-showman-featurettes/